# TestNG data provider convert object 2d array to Hashtable - throws MethodMatcherException

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have Data provider defined to get the data from excel sheet and passing it to the test method of testing. I am able to get and read data from excel but when passing it to the testing method under test it throws `MethodMatcherException`

Code from dataProvider

```
@DataProvider(name = "testdatasupply")
public Object[][] ReadDetails() throws IOException {
    HashMap<String,String> rowdata=new HashMap<String,String>();
    File file=new File("src/main/resources/TestData.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheet("API");
    Row key=sheet.getRow(0);
    int rowcount=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int columncount=key.getLastCellNum();
    Object[][] data1 =new Object[rowcount][columncount];
    for(int i=0;i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1;i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i+1);
        if(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                rowdata.put(key.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
            }
            data1[i][0]=rowdata;
            System.out.println(data1[i][0]);
        }
    }
    return data1;
}
```

And my testing class under test .

```
@Test(dataProvider = "testdatasupply",dataProviderClass = TestData.ReadData.class)
public void APITesting(Hashtable<String,String> data){
    System.out.println(data);
    String API= data.get("API Name");
    switch (API.toLowerCase()){
        case "petstore/get":
            System.out.println(data.get("ID"));
        case "petstore/post":
            System.out.println(data.get("ID")+"from secnd");
    }
}
```

When I run above code, I am getting `org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException`: which shows return type is not matching as expected. Since I have more columns , getting it as individual string is not helping as I have to create more number of variables.

```
 [public void TestRunner.main.testrunner.APITesting(java.util.Hashtable)] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
Data provider mismatch
Method: APITesting([Parameter{index=0, type=java.util.Hashtable, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
```

Can anyone suggest best way to get this as `Hashtable` or what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `rowdata` is of type `HashMap`. So why are you using `Hashtable` as the parameter type to your test method?

Comment: That dosent matter right? Since we are putting it to Object 2D array ? I tried using Hashmap too . Still same error

Comment: Ideally, if you had used `HashMap` then it should work as mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68450269/7804477) Also, the type **does** matter even though you are putting it in a 2d arry. testNG checks by matching the argument types of the test method, it is `Hashtable` against the object which is being provided from the data provided (`HashMap`) and then it invokes `Class.isInstance`. So, essentially `Hashtable.class.isInstance(objectOfHashMap)` is happening and that returns `false`

Comment: which version of testng are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataprovider returns a `HashMap` for each test, while your test method expects a parameter of type `Hashtable`. These two are different data types. But both have a common interface `Map`.

So, in your test method, change as below:

```java
public void APITesting(Map<String,String> data)
```

In your data provider change as: (not required, but recommended):

```java
Map<String,String> rowdata=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Also, your code dataprovider code has some issues - The same map, `rowdata` is being used inside the loop, So for every test run the data passed to the test method would be the same since you are doing `data1[i][0]=rowdata;` within the `i` loop.

I assume you should be doing:

```java
for(int i=0;i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1;i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i+1);
    // initialize the map here.
    Map<String,String> rowdata=new HashMap<String,String>();
    if(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            rowdata.put(key.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
        }
        data1[i][0]=rowdata;
        System.out.println(data1[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems incorrect and you can do the following things:

**1). First Solution:**

a) @Test method cannot have `public void APITesting(Hashtable<String,String> data)` try to replace it with `public void APITesting(String API, String ID)`

b) In the data provider try to return the ID and API. You need to parse data before returning it. In the dataprovider method you need to get the API and ID and then pass it to the `@test` method.

```
data1[i][0]=APIData;
data1[i][1]=ID;
```

**Code:**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "testdatasupply",dataProviderClass = TestData.ReadData.class)
    public void APITesting(String API, String ID) {
        switch (API.toLowerCase()) {
            case "petstore/get":
                System.out.println(ID);
            case "petstore/post":
                System.out.println(ID + "from secnd");
        }
}
```

**2) Second Solution:**

As you cannot pass the `public void APITesting(Hashtable<String,String> data)` try to again replace it with `public void APITesting(String data)` and then convert the string to hashtable again.

**Code:**

```
   @Test(dataProvider = "testdatasupply",dataProviderClass = TestData.ReadData.class)
    public void APITesting(String data) {
        String a = data.toString();
        a = a.replaceAll("[{}]","");

    System.out.println(a);
    // New HashTable obj
    Hashtable<String, String> hashTable
            = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    // split the String by a comma
    String parts[] = a.split(",");

    // iterate the parts and add them to a HashTable
    for (String part : parts) {
        String subData[] = part.split("=");
        String api = subData[0].trim();
        String id = subData[1].trim();
        // Add to hashTable
        hashTable.put(api, id);
    }
    System.out.println("String to HashTable: " + hashTable);

    System.out.println(hashTable.get("API"));
    System.out.println(hashTable.get("id"));

    String API= hashTable.get("API Name");
    switch (API.toLowerCase()){
        case "petstore/get":
            System.out.println(hashTable.get("ID"));
        case "petstore/post":
            System.out.println(hashTable.get("ID")+"from secnd");
    }
}
```

Comment: From the 2d array `object[][]`, testNG tries to pass each "row" (not the full `object[][]`) as input to the test method. In the question, each row contains a `HashMap`. So testNG tries to pass this `HashMap` to  the test method. But the parameter of test method is a `Hashtable`. This is what causes the mismatch. (Added few more details in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68450269/7804477) )

Comment: Dataprovider could be used to pass an object of "any" type to the test method. It would be helpful if could please explain as to why you think such a declaration of the test method is incorrect?